# Xilinx FPGA Input data timing constraint

Tags: fpga, xilinx, timing-analysis

I'm using Xilinx Spartan 6 Automotive FPGA. My FPGA design has a SPI interface to a external peripheral.

From FPGA to the peripheral, I have these SPI related signals:

1. spi clk
2. spi data (mosi) - the data is presented on the falling edge
   of the spi clk

From the peripheral to FPGA:

1. spi data (miso) - the data is presented on the rising edge using the spi clk received from FPGA

FPGA samples the MISO SPI data using the SPI CLK falling edge - it's generated internally (via a state machine).

Now, I want to add a timing constraint on the MISO pin to ensure the MISO data reaches the first sync component (a latch clocked by spi clk) without violating the setup and hold time. Which Xilinx timing constraint should I use?

Some options I was looking into are OFFSET IN, FROM/TO...

I perfer OFFSET IN because it relates data to the clock, but I cannot figure how to specify an internal clock (I don't have SPI clk loopback). FROM/TO might work, but it's not relative to the clock.

Comment: Isn't the peripheral responsible for generating MISO? How do you expect the FPGA synthesis tool to change the timing of a signal generated by the peripheral?

Comment: that's not what i want to do. my spi_clk goes out to the peripheral, which uses that clk to generate MISO data. at the MISO input pin on my FPGA, the MISO data may not align with my spi_clk anymore because of the delay from the peripheral. another delay (the one i'm trying to constrain) is the delay from FPGA pin to the first sync component. This delay is internal at FPGA and could be properly constrained during synthesis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do understand, that you have an internal clock SYS_CLK, which you use to drive the state machine generating SPI_CLK.

The flip-flop which generates SPI_CLK should be located in IOB, to ensure  deterministic timing between SYS_CLK and SPI_CLK (you can specify the required maximum delay for SPI_CLK, using the OFFSET OUT).

Then you can specify your constraints using OFFSET IN (for MOSI) and OFFSET OUT (for MISO) with respect to SYS_CLK, considering the delay between SYS_CLK and SPI_CLK.